# How to check and replace <img> tags present in an HTML string with emoji codes in PHP?

Tags: php, html, html-parsing, domdocument, emoji

I want to pass an HTML string which may contain one or more `<img>` tags and some text as per user's choice.

I've one set of emoji codes in the form of an associative array. If any file name from the src attribute of any `<img>` tag present in a HTML string matches with any of the key present in emoji's array then the `<img>` tag should get replace with the respective matching code. Other things such as text and non-matching elements should remain as it is.

For achieving this I tried below code but I'm getting blank in return from the function. Can someone please correct the mistake I'm making in my code or if you have any other better and efficient solution to this problem please let me know.

If you look at my program I've put in comments with the output at important steps.

```
<?php
  function string_sanitizer($feed_status) { 
    /*echo $feed_status.PHP_EOL;
<img src="http://54.174.50.242/file/pic/emoticon/default/smile.png" alt="Smile" title="Smile" title="v_middle" /><img src="http://54.174.50.242/file/pic/emoticon/default/smile.png" alt="Smile" title="Smile" title="v_middle" /><img src="http://54.174.50.242/file/pic/emoticon/default/smile.png" alt="Smile" title="Smile" title="v_middle" />*/

    $temp = $feed_status;
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($feed_status, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
    $imageTags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
    /*print_r($imageTags);
      echo PHP_EOL;        
    DOMNodeList Object
    (
        [length] => 3
    )*/
    $replacements = array(
      'evilgrin.png' => '\ue404',
      'grin.png' => '\ue415',
      'happy.png' => '\ue057',
      'smile.png' => '\ue056',
      'surprised.png' => '\ue107',
      'tongue.png' => '\ue105',
      'unhappy.png' => '\ue403',
      'waii.png' => '\ue407',
      'wink.png' => '\ue405',
    );

    // regression 
    $i = $imageTags->length - 1;
    /*echo "Value of i:".$i.PHP_EOL;
      Value of i:2*/     
    while($i > -1) { 
      //echo "Loop Counter :".$i.PHP_EOL;

      $tag = $imageTags->item($i);
      /*print_r($tag);
      echo PHP_EOL;*/
      $basename = basename($tag->getAttribute('src'));
      //echo $basename.PHP_EOL;
      if(isset($replacements[$basename])) { //echo "In a loop :".$i.PHP_EOL; 
        //if the file name matches make replacements
        $r = $replacements[$basename];
        //echo "Value of r : ".$r.PHP_EOL;
        $text = $doc->createTextNode($r);
        /*print_r($text);
        echo PHP_EOL;*/ 
        $tag->parentNode->replaceChild($text, $tag);
        /*print_r($tag);
        echo PHP_EOL;*/
      }
      $i--;
    }
    //I think till here everything works fine but issue is in saving this newly generated HTML

    // append to string container again
    $feed_status = '';
    foreach($doc->childNodes->item(0)->childNodes as $e) {
      $feed_status .= addslashes($doc->saveHTML($e));
    }   

    if($feed_status == '') {
      $feed_status = strip_tags($temp);        
    }
    return $feed_status;
  }

$str_sample = '<img src="http://54.174.50.242/file/pic/emoticon/default/smile.png" alt="Smile" title="Smile" title="v_middle" /><img src="http://54.174.50.242/file/pic/emoticon/default/smile.png" alt="Smile" title="Smile" title="v_middle" /><img src="http://54.174.50.242/file/pic/emoticon/default/smile.png" alt="Smile" title="Smile" title="v_middle" />';
$jumbo = string_sanitizer($str_sample);
echo $jumbo;
?>
```

In above case I want the output as **'\ue056\ue056\ue056'** since all the three `<img>` tags contain the matching file name in their `src attribute` i.e. smile.jpg so all the `<img>` should get replace with code '\ue056'.

Comment: Do you mean that the returned value is empty (`''`) ? Can you please make sure that `display_errors` is `on` and that there are no errors?

Comment: @OfirBaruch:Yes, empty means ' '. There are no more errors, even you can copy-paste and run the code on your local machine. Actually the code should work but I'm not understanding where the issue lies.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is how you set your [options](http://php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php) in `loadHtml()`. Change

```
$doc->loadHTML($feed_status, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
```

to

```
$doc->loadHTML($feed_status, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
```

because `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` turns off the automatic adding of implied html/body ([ref](http://php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php)), but your code uses `$tag->parentNode`, so your fragments will need a parent tag.

After the above change, your script will output

> \\ue056\\ue056\\ue056

---

**Note:** You will get the double slash because you have

```
$feed_status .= addslashes($doc->saveHTML($e));
```

which will add a backslash to the backslash in `\ue056` ([ref](http://php.net/addslashes)).

---

**Note:** HTML fragments like

```
<img src=".../smile.png" alt="Smile" title="Smile" title="v_middle" />
```

will throw warnings when parsed because you have **two** title attributes. Perhaps one of them should be a class?

---

**Demo:** http://ideone.com/QRFUQm

Comment: Still I'm getting blank string.

Comment: This program is working fine on my local machine too after making the change you suggested but it's not working in my system. Is there any possibility of due to the change in some configuration file/module enabled/disabled the issue is coming when I run the same code in my system?

Comment: First, I'm glad I got it working for you. This is now a new problem. Suggest you enable error reporting in your system and see what is reported back. Perhaps some XML modules aren't installed.

Comment: What are those XML modules?

Comment: For example, if some xml modules are not installed: http://vanillaforums.org/discussion/22002/solved-fatal-error-class-domdocument-not-found-in-var-www-html-community-answers (but we really need an error log to be sure)